# Sub Categories on drop-down menu populated by MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to creating menus via MySQL, and need a tree structure. However, it is not working, as shown on http://www.mattmaclennan.co.uk/a2

What I need to do is group the model numbers into each category, can't figure out how to do it though. Here is my PHP code:

```
<?
$output = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bikes, bikeTypes WHERE bikes.model_id = bikeTypes.model_id");
echo "<ul>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($output))
{
echo "<li>" . $row['model'];
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li>" . $row['bikeName'] . "</li>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</li>";
}
echo "<ul>";
?>
```

I have a table with the Category in (e.g. Adventure, 125CC etc) and a table for the model numbers. It is finding the data fine, it's just organising it in the right structure which is confusing. Any ideas guys?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly and if Category in the same table? If so add "GROUP BY bikeCategory" to the end of your mysql query statement.

Comment: Hey there! I tried that, and it only shows the first record of each category, the site is updated if you want to have a look. Thanks!

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the 
community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See
 the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared
 statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://in3.php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you.
 If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO).
 Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$result = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($output))
{
  $result[$row['your_category_field_name']][] = $row;
}

foreach ($result as $category => $values) {
  echo '<h4>'.$category.'</h4><ul>';
  foreach ($values as $value) {
    echo "<li>" . $value['model'];
    echo "<li>" . $value['bikeName'] . "</li>";
  }
  echo '</ul>';
```

}